# java - [Apache Curator] How to properly close curator

Tags: java, apache, apache-zookeeper, fallback, apache-curator

I'm trying to implement a fallback logic on my connection to Zookeeper using Apache Curator, basically I have two sets of connection strings and if I receive a LOST state on my state listener I try to reconnect my curator client on the another set of connection strings. I could simple put all machines on the same connection string but I want to connect on fallback only when all machines for the default cluster are offline.

The problem is that I can't close the previous curator client when I try to change to the fallback cluster, I keep receiving the LOG message saying that curator is trying to reconnect, even after I connect on the fallback set of zookeepers. Below you can find a code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
final ConnectionStateListener listener = (client1, state) -> {
    if (state == ConnectionState.LOST) {
        reconnect();
    }
};
```

And the reconnect method (will change the lastHost to the fallback cluster):

```
if (client != null) {
    client.close();
}
...
client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(
        lastHost,
        sessionTimeout,
        connectionTimeout,
        retryPolicy);
...
client.start()
```

I can successfully connect on the new set of connection strings (fallback) but the problem is that the previous client keep trying to connect on the previous connection strings.

Looking at the `close()` method I saw that curator only close things if the State of the client is STARTED, I think that's why curator keep trying to connect on the previous cluster.

Is there a way to close() the curator client without having the STARTED state on it?

If not is there another way to implement this logic (fallback zookeeper servers) on curator?

Thanks.